# Echo Table PHP and added Dropdown list, how to use the drop down in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

I have successfully called this from a database. I want to include a combobox (dropdown) in a PHP string to echo it and form a table.

The PHP to do that is looking thus

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect , Reason: '.mysqli_connect_error());
$sql = "select * from crime_db_table";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $result_table = "<TR valign=top>
    <TD width=127 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['case_number']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=109 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['crime_type']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=90 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['fullname']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=122 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['address']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=118 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['telephone']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=157 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['incident_date']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=103 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><a href=http://google.com title=><font size=2>Image.jpg</font></a></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=138 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['crime_desc']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=138 height=26 align=center><font size=2><select name=dropdown id=dropdown><option>Please Select</option><option>Modify</option><option>Delete</option></select></font></TD>
    </TR>";

    echo $result_table;
  }
}else{
  echo "<div><font face=Verdana><B>No Results Found</B></font></div>";
}
  $con->close();
?>
```

Which works pretty fine, but the major challenge I have is the `<select></select>` which is embedded into the PHP code in this case.
As you can see `<select name=dropdown id=dropdown><option>Please Select</option><option>Modify</option><option>Delete</option></select>` is the full drop down.

How do i do it that when i select modify, it loads another PHP page where the user can edit the form and save data to the MySQL database and when i click delete, it removes the data from the MySQL table.

**Edit**

New Source code Looks thus:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect , Reason: '.mysqli_connect_error());
$sql = "select * from crime_db_table";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $result_table = "<TR valign=top>
    <TD width=127 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['case_number']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=109 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['crime_type']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=90 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['fullname']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=122 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['address']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=118 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['telephone']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=157 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['incident_date']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=103 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><a href=http://google.com title=><font size=2>Image.jpg</font></a></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=138 height=26 align=center><div class=wpmd>
    <div align=center><font size=2>".$row['crime_desc']."</font></div>
    </div>
    </TD>
    <TD width=138 height=26 align=center><font size=2><select name=dropdown id=dropdown onchange="handleSelection(this)"><option>Please Select</option><option>Modify</option><option>Delete</option></select></font></TD>
    </TR>";

    echo $result_table;
  }
}else{
  echo "<div><font face=Verdana><B>No Results Found</B></font></div>";
}
  $con->close();
?>
```

Worse now, it does not even open the form as i created.

Comment: did you make it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve the functionality you described, you can modify your PHP code as follows:

A. Update the select element in the `$result_table` string to include an `onchange` event:

```
<select name=dropdown id=dropdown onchange="handleSelection(this)">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option value="modify">Modify</option>
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
</select>
```

B. Add a JavaScript function to handle the selection and redirect the user to the appropriate PHP page:

```
<script>
function handleSelection(selectElement) {
  var selectedOption = selectElement.value;
  if (selectedOption === 'modify') {
    window.location.href = 'edit_page.php?case_number=<?php echo $row["case_number"]; ?>';
  } else if (selectedOption === 'delete') {
    window.location.href = 'delete_page.php?case_number=<?php echo $row["case_number"]; ?>';
  }
}
</script>
```

C. Create two separate PHP pages: `edit_page.php` and `delete_page.php`, to handle the modification and deletion functionality, respectively. In these pages, you can retrieve the `case_number` value from the URL using `$_GET['case_number']` and perform the necessary database operations.

For example, in `edit_page.php`:

```
<?php
$case_number = $_GET['case_number'];

// Retrieve the data for the specified case_number from the database and pre-fill the form for editing

// Update the data in the database based on the user's modifications

// Redirect the user back to the original page
header('Location: original_page.php');
exit;
?>
```

And in `delete_page.php`:

```
<?php
$case_number = $_GET['case_number'];

// Delete the data for the specified case_number from the database

// Redirect the user back to the original page
header('Location: original_page.php');
exit;
?>
```

Make sure to replace `edit_page.php`, `delete_page.php`, and `original_page.php` with the actual filenames or URLs of your pages.

With these modifications, when the user selects "Modify" from the dropdown, they will be redirected to the `edit_page.php` with the corresponding `case_number` in the URL. Similarly, selecting "Delete" will redirect the user to the `delete_page.php` with the appropriate `case_number` in the URL.